# How to do 301 permanent redirect when some filenames have been changed

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

We have a very old website that we're updating. All of the files in the old site have .htm extensions that we want to change to .html extensions. Some of the filenames will remain the same (except for the extension) while others we wish to change. The thought was to use RedirectMatch 301 to redirect all of the htm pages to the html extension and then list Redirect 301 only for the pages that have new filenames.

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*).htm$ http://www.example.com$1.html
Redirect 301 /old-page-1.htm http://www.example.com/new-page-1.html
Redirect 301 /old-page-2.htm http://www.example.com/new-page-2.html
```

Is that the best way to get this done or is the better way?

Answer (score 0):

Have specific rules first and then the generic one. Also it is better to use `RedirectMatch` for all your rules like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /old-page-1\.htm$ http://www.example.com/new-page-1.html
RedirectMatch 301 /old-page-2\.htm$ http://www.example.com/new-page-2.html
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.+)\.htm$ http://www.example.com$1.html
```

Make sure to test this in a new browser to avoid old cache.